# Eternal Doctoral Thesis

Tags: phd, psychology

How can I help a friend who is working on a doctoral thesis since about 10 years?

It seems to me that achieving a doctoral degree is close to impossible at that point. I am sure that there is no actual progress on the thesis out of a lack of motivation and too little motivation to try something else.

He evades questions about the thesis, but at least tries to pretend that work progresses, if slowly.
I think there is no gain in helping him in the short term. By that I mean that currently my friend seems to be happy enough, and it does not feel like he just pretends to be. Also, he gets financial support from his family.

But my judgement might be off, since I only know him since about five years, and I heard an other opinion stating that he changed significantly. Also, when I try to put myself in my friends position, I would likely be devastated to the core. But try as I might, I don't think that I could repress my problems and veil them to the outside for long.

Putting that aside, I suppose that he will suffer social and financial insecurity in the long term, when his parents will not support him any more. So in this respect, it seems to be a good idea for him to get a job, except that he would need to face that he failed at his academic career to a larger extend. Even though it seems to be a rational choice to me, assuming that I manage to convince him to apply for a job, it might have psychological repercussions and damage our friendship.

Nonetheless, I would still like to push him to get a job if it can be done. So instead of asking about other options or more insight; Do I have a chance to nudge him into getting a job and if so how can it be done?

There is no fail-safe formula or instant solution to this problem, but if you have advice apart from the actual question please leave a comment/link.

Answer (score 5):

The tricky aspect of this question is that you don't seem to know for sure how much progress he is actually making.  Ten years is a long time to spend in graduate school, but not unheard of.  If he is slowly making progress and supporting him isn't too much of a burden on his family, then he might be better off finishing in eleven or twelve years total, rather than quitting after ten.  (Finishing may feel much better than quitting, even if he doesn't get an academic job at all.  There are also different sorts of academic jobs: he might benefit from the degree if he ends up in high school or community college teaching, where having a Ph.D. could mean something and they might not care if it was a long, slow process.)

If he is making no progress at all and will most likely never complete the degree, then doing something else with his life would be a better choice, but of course that's a very difficult conversation to have.  If this is the case, then his advisor should already be dealing with this issue, but it's possible that the advisor is avoiding the topic.

Another difficult case is if he could complete the degree, but nobody wants to support him for long enough, or if his plans for what he'll do with the degree are unrealistic.

My recommendation is that you shouldn't intervene unless you have an exceptionally close relationship (romantic partner, best friend, etc.).  Otherwise, it's really none of your business and I doubt you'll have a productive conversation.

If you do have a close enough relationship, then the first step is to have a honest conversation about how things are going, what his hopes are for the future, what's realistically possible, what the trade-offs are, what his fallback plan is, etc.  Without that, all you're doing is guessing.  Merely having this conversation could be a useful way for him to clarify his thoughts, so I'd start with that rather than focusing on making changes.  Discussing potential changes can wait until you have reached consensus on the situation he is facing.

Comment: [Some people take upwards of 4 decades to complete their Ph.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_May#Astrophysics) ;)